# SAS PROC LOGISTIC: Hosmer and Lemeshow test is good but Gini is bad?

Tags: logistic, sas, gini

I am using `PROC LOGISTIC` along with `Class` statements to do binary logit model(default=1,non-default=0) on a bank loan dataset where I have 7 numeric independent variables and 1 categorical independent variable.

Hosmer and Lemeshow test yields a `p = 0.6757`, and `Percent Concordant = 73.3` so the model is fine I think.

To my dismay Gini is coming up as `0.2305`, and ks is only `35.1`.

I there any way I can do anything about the results or am I missing anything?

```
%let Keepvar= Age_in_years Level_of_education Years_with_Current_Employer 
   Years_at_Current_Address Household_income_in_thousands Debt_to_income_ratio 
   Credit_card_debt__in_thousands Other_debt_in__in_thousands; 
PROC LOGISTIC DATA = work.bankloan descending outest=estimates;
    class Level_of_education (ref='1') / param=ref;
    MODEL Defaulted = &keepvar/selection=backword rsquare lackfit;
RUN;

%macro rankorder(data=, est=, dependent= );
    proc score data = &data score = &est out = mlscore type = parms;
    var &keepvar;
run;

data mlscore;
    set mlscore;
    prob = exp(&dependent.2) /(1+exp(&dependent.2));
run;

proc rank data = mlscore out = mlrankscore groups =10;
    var prob;
    ranks probrank;
run;

proc sql;
select probrank, avg(prob) as probability, count(*) as total,avg(&dependent) as 
  Act_Avg_Response, sum(&dependent) as sum_of_response from mlrankscore group by 
  probrank order by probrank descending;
quit;
%mend;
%rankorder(data=bankloan, est=estimates, dependent=Defaulted);
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

However, the HL test and the GINI test are for different things. HL is a test of goodness of fit of the model, GINI is a test of how much the model improves your prediction of the DV. KS usually stands for Kolmoogorov Smirnov and I am not sure what you are using it for, here.

Comment: I am trying a decile analysis; The maximum difference across that 10 buckets is called the KS value

Comment: %let Keepvar=
Age_in_years
Level_of_education
Years_with_Current_Employer
Years_at_Current_Address
Household_income_in_thousands
Debt_to_income_ratio
Credit_card_debt__in_thousands
Other_debt_in__in_thousands                              
;
PROC LOGISTIC DATA = work.bankloan descending outest=estimates;
class Level_of_education (ref='1') / param=ref ;
 MODEL Defaulted = &keepvar/selection=backword rsquare lackfit;
RUN;

Comment: %macro rankorder(data=, est=, dependent= );
proc score data = &data score = &est out = mlscore type = parms;  var &keepvar; run;
data mlscore; set mlscore; prob = exp(&dependent.2) /(1+exp(&dependent.2)); run;
proc rank data = mlscore out = mlrankscore groups =10; var prob; ranks probrank; run;
proc sql; select probrank, avg(prob) as probability, count(*) as total,avg(&dependent) as Act_Avg_Response, 
sum(&dependent) as sum_of_response from mlrankscore group by probrank order by probrank descending; 
quit;
%mend;
%rankorder(data=bankloan, est=estimates, dependent=Defaulted);

Comment: May I get your email then I can send you the whole code...actually after this there is another big macro for calculating Gini, KS etc.

Comment: I don't think I need your whole code. The HL test answers a different question than GINI or KS. The latter two are about how good the model is - how much the variables help the prediction. The former is about whether the model fits.

Comment: [sigh] @purnendumaity, please edit your question to show the code. It is simply unreadable in the comments. Click on the orange question mark in the upper right of the edit window to get the help on how this is to be done.